# imacros don't show commas from csv file

Tags: imacros

Im new to iMacros and I tried a small iMacros to fill out a form.
Here is the code:

```html
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Sahil\Desktop\cloth.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=the website/
FRAME NAME=links
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=TXT:MEN
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=TXT:SHORTS
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ismForm ATTR=ID:amount CONTENT={{!COL2}}
```

And it does everything as it should BUT in my datasource file I have in my COL2  0,123 but it recognizes  it being 0 and then 123, instead of 0,123. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes between the commas in your csv file. Below is an example

Example: 0,123 -> "0","123" should work

or you can change the delimiter from , to ;

For that put following code before SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Sahil\Desktop\cloth.csv

SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER ;